# Does Firefox OS support developing digital signage on Panasonic TV?

Tags: firefox-os, firefox-developer-tools, html5-apps

I need to know if Firefox OS on the Panasonic TV devices allows me to develop a digital signage application that looks like this

```html
<pre>
------------------------------
|                  |         |
|                  |         |
|       TV         |  .html  | 
|                  |         |
------------------------------
|      .html                 |
------------------------------   
</pre>
```

Comment: I suggest you ask this on product forums or in chat. This question could be answered by a simple comment, like a 'yes'. I downvoted, but have not flagged, because I think it can be edited to be improved

Answer (score 3):

You could always use iframe to layout web pages like that in the app. If the app requires additional control over the webpages, it will need the `browser` permission in order to use the `Browser API`.

However for the current version of the Firefox OS TV, although Panasonic has implemented a set of TV API based on W3C draft (https://w3c.github.io/tvapi/spec/), we don't know if it is opened to 3rd party apps. We'll consult them for the usage of the API.

Comment: Questions regarding Firefox OS development could also be posted to dev-fxos@lists.mozilla.org https://lists.mozilla.org/listinfo/dev-fxos

Comment: 1st while researching this issue Mozilla clearly stated questions about Firefox OS (FxOS) should be asked here on the stack.

2nd Mozilla documentation for FxOS on TV has not been updated since Panasonic adopted FxOS and released product here in USA just this past week. 

3rd I'll start using dev-fxos@lists.mozilla.org however I (we) need to know if FxOS supports Picture-in-Picture -now- as Mozilla has stated so the diagram shown above can be developed. PIP requires rescaling the TV program to fit into our arbitrary DOM objects. Mozilla marketing and dev documentation is currently conflicting.